# How to name the type of an associated function in Rust?

Tags: function, generics, rust, closures, traits

I'm trying to write code which is generic over an operation, but also has convenience functions for commonly used ones, like addition, which I want to define for all types `T: Add`.

This works fine if I define standalone functions since I can use `impl Trait` in the return value to hide the opaque type.

However, if I want to define this function inside a trait, I am forced to name the type of `<T as Add>::add`. How can I do this?

```
use std::ops::Add;

struct Operation<T, F>
where
    F: Fn(T, T) -> T,
{
    arg: T,
    f: F,
}

fn addition<T>(arg: T) -> Operation<T, impl Fn(T, T) -> T>
where
    T: Add<Output = T>,
{
    Operation { arg, f: T::add }
}

trait Addable<T>
where
    T: Add<Output = T>,
{
    fn addition(self) -> Operation<T, impl Fn(T, T) -> T>;
    //fn addition(self) -> Operation<T, ???>;
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0562]: `impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and inherent method return types
  --> src/main.rs:22:39
   |
22 |     fn addition(self) -> Operation<T, impl Fn(T, T) -> T>;
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason `impl Trait` isn't allowed in the return position of trait methods is because there can be multiple implementations of the method, whereas `impl Trait` is only valid if there's a single implementation of the function or method.

One option would be to use a boxed trait object closure:

```rust
trait Addable<T>
where
    T: Add<Output = T>,
{
    fn addition(self) -> Operation<T, Box<dyn Fn(T, T) -> T>>;
}
```

However, since it seems unlikely that the closure would ever need to capture variables from its environment you can use a plain function pointer instead. This saves you an unnecessary heap allocation. Here's a simple `i32` example using a plain function pointer in the trait method return type:

```rust
trait Addable<T>
where
    T: Add<Output = T>,
{
    fn addition(self) -> Operation<T, fn(T, T) -> T>;
}

struct SomeType {
    arg: i32,
}

impl Addable<i32> for SomeType {
    fn addition(self) -> Operation<i32, fn(i32, i32) -> i32> {
        Operation {
            arg: self.arg,
            f: i32::add,
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a generic example using plain function pointer in the trait method return type:

```rust
trait Addable<T>
where
    T: Add<Output = T>,
{
    fn addition(self) -> Operation<T, fn(T, T) -> T>;
}

struct SomeType<T> {
    arg: T,
}

impl<T> Addable<T> for SomeType<T>
    where T: Add + Add<Output = T>
{
    fn addition(self) -> Operation<T, fn(T, T) -> T> {
        Operation {
            arg: self.arg,
            f: T::add,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't want to make an extra allocation, so `fn` is exactly what I was looking for.